# How to add different style for a component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components

I was trying to add different styles for a component in react nect.js. Below I've mentioned my code for button component

`import styles from "./button.module.css"; const Button = props =>{ return( <div> <button className={styles.button}>{props.text}</button> </div> ) } export default Button;`

I have to use this button component two times in my webpage, but with different styles.(for example, I want first component with blue background and another one with green background. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import Button from "@/components/button";
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="actions">
        <Button className="live" text = "Go Live"/>
        <Button className="userAdd" text = "Add users"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

I tried adding different classname for the button component and adding style to that class. But no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches:

##### Approach 1

Pass in a colour as a prop to `Button`. Here I have a base class called `.button` (containing, say, padding/margin information for all types of button) which I'm combining with the colour class in an array in the `Button` component, and passing that to the button `className` attribute.

Note: you could use the [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility library instead of the array if your class composition gets too unwieldy for an array.

`button.modules.css`

```
.button { padding: 0.4em; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
```

`Button.jsx`

```
function Button({ text, color }) {
  
  const cn = [
    style.button,
    style[color]
  ].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <button className={cn} type="button">
      {text}
    </button>
  );

}

function Example() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Button text="Go live" color="blue" />
      <Button text="Add users" color="green" />
    </section>
  );
}
```

##### Approach 2

Very similar but using `composes` to use the base `.button` class within each colour class to inherit its properties. This means that you don't have to use an array to build the className.

`button.modules.css`

```
.button { padding: 0.4em; }
.blue { composes: button; background-color: blue; }
.green { composes: button; background-color: green; }
```

`Button.jsx`

```
function Button({ text, color }) {      
  return (
    <button className={style[color]} type="button">
      {text}
    </button>
  );
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Button text="Go live" color="blue" />
      <Button text="Add users" color="green" />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the idea of className={style[color]}. Should I create an array named color? I'm a newbie here.

Comment: `color` comes from the prop you pass in @UnnikrishnanKJ

Answer (score 1):

First, you can make the `Button` component use the passed in `className` prop, adding it to the base class. You can decide whether to apply these additional classes to the `<button>` or the parent `<div>`.

```
const Button = ({className = '', text}) => 
        <div><button className={styles.button + ' ' + className}>{text}</button></div>;
```

Then, you can add more classes to `button.module.css`:

```css
.live {
    /* ... */
}
.userAdd {
    /* ... */
}
```

Finally, pass more classes in the `Home` component.

```
import buttonStyles from './button.module.css';
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="actions">
        <Button className={buttonStyles.live} text="Go Live"/>
        <Button className={buttonStyles.userAdd} text="Add users"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```